# file_get_contents Warning: Failed to open stream

Tags: php, arrays, json, file, file-get-contents

I have a question here, tho, I've been digging here at SO, it seems I can't find the real deal;

I am trying the ff:

```
<?php
  $filename = $trantype . $delimiter . $dateToday . $fileExtension ;
  //echo $filename . '<br/>';

  $fileToOpen = $filepath . $filename;
  echo "File To Open: " . $fileToOpen . '<br/>';

  $string = file_get_contents($fileToOpen);
  //$string = file_get_contents("../transactions/o/O_20120809.xx");
  $json_array = json_decode($string, true);
  echo "Echo: " . $json_array[0]['itemheader_sysid'] . '<br/>';
  echo "The File Contents: " . $string;
?>
```

The $string = file_get_contents('../transaction/o/O_20120809.xx') works smoothly on the other hand the $string = file_get_contents($fileToOpen); doesn't seem to work and is giving me the ff: error;

```
 Warning: file_get_contents(../transactions/o/0_20120809.xx) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\xx\helper\upo.php on line 19
```

why so?

Anyone please?

Comment: Your question has `o/O` for one filename and `o/0` in the other. Is this a typing accident? Otherwise it could be your problem

Comment: you have a very sharp eye right there... oh how can I thank you... I guess I have to lay away using Capitalize O as is it mistakenly overlooked as 0.. many thanks for saving me..